# Consuming REST API secured with Keycloak as Broker for OAUTH2-Provider

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have to consume REST API of an app secured with Keycloak, which serves as Broker to OAUTH2-Provider.

For this aim I use OAuth2RestTemplate and ResourceOwnerPasswordDetails.
I can obtain an access token from third-part provider without any problem, but how have I use it further, it is the question. Using it in a Header as Bearer doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

OAuthConfig.java

```
@Bean
public ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource(){
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
resource.setAccessTokenUri(env.getProperty("access.token.uri"));
resource.setClientId(env.getProperty("access.client.id"));
resource.setGrantType("password");
resource.setClientSecret(env.getProperty("access.client.secret"));
resource.setUsername(env.getProperty("access.client.username"));
resource.setPassword(env.getProperty("access.client.password"));
resource.setScope(Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("access.client.scope")));
return resource;
}
```

Service to obtain an Access Token

```
@Autowired
private OAuthConfig authConfig;

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(){
ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(authConfig.resource(), new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
return accessToken;
}
```

OAuth2RestTemplate

```
@Autowired private ProdAuthService authService;

OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(authConfig.resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(authService.getAccessToken())); 
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
header.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authService.getAccessToken());
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(header);
ResponseEntity <ProcessInstanceLogWrapper> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ProcessInstanceLogWrapper>(){});
ProcessInstanceLogWrapper json = response.getBody();
```

An error I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.AccessTokenRequiredException: OAuth2 access denied.
```

In Keycloak we use also Authorizaion URL, but it seems not possible to use it with ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails. It could also according to my opinion be the case, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did u manage to get this working ?

Comment: no way... At least, I hadn't resolved this problem. If you have the same problem, the fastest, but unfortunately not the securest solution could be to enable a basic-auth in undertow and use it... I've made so...

Comment: I managed to get it working. Will share the code tomorrow.

Comment: It sounds good! I'm looking forward your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate Creation:

```
 protected RestKeyCloakClient()
{
    MultiValueMap<String, String> header = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    OAuth2RestTemplate client;
    DefaultAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext context = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest);
    OAuth2AccessTokenSupport support = new OAuth2AccessTokenSupport()
    {
    };
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormOAuth2AccessTokenMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new FormOAuth2ExceptionHttpMessageConverter());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    jackson.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
    messageConverters.add(jackson);
    support.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    client = new OAuth2RestTemplate(getAuthDetails(null, null), context);
    client.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    client.setRequestFactory(factory);
    token = client.getAccessToken();
}
```

ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails:

```
private ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails getAuthDetails(String userName, String userPwd)
{

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager()
    {
        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }
    }};

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails authDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    authDetails.setAccessTokenUri(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getoAuth2tokenRequestUrl());
    authDetails.setClientId(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getoAuth2ClientId());
    authDetails.setClientSecret(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getoAuth2SecretToken());
    authDetails.setGrantType(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getOauth2granttype());
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userName) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(userPwd)) {
        authDetails.setUsername(userName);
        authDetails.setPassword(userPwd);
    } else {
        authDetails.setUsername(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getOauth2UserName());
        authDetails.setPassword(LoggerAndReader.getInstance().getOauth2password());
    }
    // authDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cn mail sn givenname uid employeeNumber"}));
    return authDetails;
}
```

Execution and futher usage:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> execute(String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object o)
{
    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(o, this.header);
    ResponseEntity<String> resp = null;
    this.header.set("Authorization", token.getTokenType() + " " + token.getValue());
    try {
        resp = this.client.exchange(url, httpMethod, request, String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String str = getStackTrace(e);
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(str, "SocketTimeoutException")) {
            throw new KeycloakHTTPClientSocketException(
                "Got a SocketTimeoutException for URL:" + url + ", HTTPMethod:" + httpMethod);
        } else
            throw new Exception(...);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

For adding further headers, you need to add them:

```
public void setThisHeaderValue(String key, String value)
{
    this.header.add(key, value);
}
```